# Converting float to integers in a specific sublist

Tags: python, list, sublist

Let's make this short.

I have a list of lists, for example

`a = [[1.0, 2.0], [6, 8]]`

What I would like to do, is to convert all values of the first sublist into integers, so the array will be

`a = [[1, 2], [6, 8]]`

Can you please tell me how to do it? I struggled with `map` already, yet I can't seem to find the correct usage. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use list comprehension for the first list (that needs transformation), and add the second list (which you don't need to change).

```py
print([[int(aa) for aa in a[0]], a[1]])
```

```py
Out[46]: [[1, 2], [6, 8]]
```

Unlike the other solutions, this does not change the 2nd part of the list in any way.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a nested list comprehension:

```
[[int(y) for y in x] for x in a]
```

Or with `map`:

```
[list(map(int, x)) for x in a]
```

Comment: I am getting an error that 'float' object is not itterable

Comment: What is the output of `print(a)` ?

Comment: Although, it seems that `a[0] = [round(x) for x in a[0]]` works, although I wonder, are those values integer upon rounding?

Comment: the output is `[[1.0, 2.0], [6, 8]]`

Comment: I'm sorry there is no way you will get 'float' object is not iterable error with your input. Could you check it again?

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to change the first delivery list, an option

```
[a for a in map(lambda n, x: list(x if n else int(x) for x in a[n]), (0, 1), a)]
```

You can assign it to a variable and then print to the screen.

```
b = [a for a in map(lambda n, x: list(x if n else int(x) for x in a[n]), (0, 1), a)]
print(b)
```

remembering that it will only transform the values ​​in the left list